# how can I fix this turret so that it moves smoothly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Okay guys I have managed to make a sprite kit game where I have a turret that shoots candies but the problem I have is that the turret doesn't move smoothly as I point a location with my finger. It just jumps to point to the location.

so here is my code below:

```
- (void) rotateSprite:(SKSpriteNode *)sprite toFace:(CGPoint)velocity rotateRadiansPerSec:(CGFloat)rotateRadiansPerSec {
float targetAngle = CGPointToAngle(velocity);
float shortest = ScalarShortestAngleBetween(sprite.zRotation, targetAngle);
float amtToRotate = rotateRadiansPerSec * _dt;
if (ABS(shortest) < amtToRotate) {
    amtToRotate = ABS(shortest);
}
sprite.zRotation += ScalarSign(shortest) * amtToRotate;
}

 - (void) movePlayerToward:(CGPoint)location {
_lastTouchLocation = location;
CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(location, _Player.position);
CGPoint direction = CGPointNormalize(offset);
_velocity = CGPointMultiplyScalar(direction, PLAYER_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC);

}

- (void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
if (_lastUpdateTime) {
    _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
}
else {
    _dt = 0;
}
_lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(_lastTouchLocation, _Player.position);
float distance = CGPointLength(offset);
if (distance < PLAYER_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC * _dt) {
    _velocity = CGPointZero;
}
else
{
    [self rotateSprite:_Player toFace:_velocity rotateRadiansPerSec:PLAYER_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC];
}
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
[self movePlayerToward:touchLocation];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
[self movePlayerToward:touchLocation];
}
```

Comment: You need to use `SKAction rotateToAngle:duration:` instead of changing `zRotation` property manually.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Zombie Conga code which uses `static const` to set fixed movement and rotation speed values.

In your code you have the line `float amtToRotate = rotateRadiansPerSec * _dt;`

Make sure you have the `rotateRadiansPerSec` value set properly as this controls the speed of your rotation.

In the Conga code, the value was:

```
static const float ZOMBIE_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC = 4 * M_PI;
```

Comment: hahaha how did you know? by the way Ray Wenderlinch is a awesome guy I really enjoyed his books. but you know how can't guess what your game is about to do a book exactly on it so sometimes for your own customization, you would need to seek more help.

Comment: Absolutely. His tutorials and books are excellent but I do find the code overly complex at times which makes customization really difficult on occasion. Glad I could be of help. Happy coding!